# Difference between stationary and non-stationary radiative transfer?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, radiative-transfer

I am currently studying [radiative transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiative_transfer). In researching this subject, I found that there is **stationary** radiative transfer and **non-stationary** radiative transfer. However, it is not clear what the difference is between these two. I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain the difference.

Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_transport_theory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, stationary or non-stationary means time dependence (energy).

Stationary radiative transfer is used as the model in the case of non-interacting particles moving through a medium for example.

> The equilibrium distribution of mutually non interacting particles propagating through a scattering
> medium is described by the stationary radiative transfer equation

https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6504

Non-stationary radiative transfer is used as the main model in cases where the particles are considered interacting and the energy levels do change with time (time dependence).

> The illumination of the dust nebula
> under the influence of radiation of a new star can be considered as an example
> of such process.
> The simplest model of non-stationary radiative transfer is a model based on
> the consideration of the one-dimensional homogeneous infinite medium with an
> energy source depending on time.

https://doi.org/10.3103/S106345411701006X

Comment: Thanks, Árpád. Do you happen to also know the answer to this https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/568083/141502 question?